# UrlConnection working with Java code but not for Android - use in Digest Authenticated Server

Tags: android

I'm using URLConnection to connect to the main server. The server implements digest authentication. If I connect to the server with java library, the connection is successful. But if I use the same code for android, the connection is rejected for the reason - username and password do not match.

Here is the code for my Java project:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Connect {

    static StringBuilder sb;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String strURL = "http://hostserver/";
        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "password";

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication (username, password.toCharArray());
                System.out.println(pa.getUserName() + ":" + new String(pa.getPassword()));
                return pa;
            }
        });

        BufferedReader in = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (java.net.ProtocolException e) {
            sb.append("User Or Password is wrong!");

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The Data is: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The above code works fine and I'm able to connect to my host server which is implementing digest authentication. I'm unable to use the same code for Android to connect. Here is my android code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Connect extends Activity {

    static StringBuilder sb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String strURL = "http://hostserver/";
        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "password";

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication (username, password.toCharArray());
                // System.out.println(pa.getUserName() + ":" + new String(pa.getPassword()));
                return pa;
            }
        });

        BufferedReader in = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (java.net.ProtocolException e) {
            sb.append("User Or Password is wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }
        }

        Log.d("DATA", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

If the same code works for Java, it should also work for Android.

The code loops in the Authenticator as it finds username and password not matching in the Android code for some reason which in fact are correct. The code runs perfect for Java project.

Comment: Please format your code accordingly.

Comment: formatted it... thanks for having a look..

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
    sb.append(line);
}
```

remove this code and write just

```
line = in.readLine().toString();
sb.append(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check  [Issue 9579: Connection to server with Digest Authentication not working](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9579).

Answer (score 0):

http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/tools-and-libs/commons-http-client/digest-authentication.html

I found this site to be helpful.